# Change one parameter value in structure does not affect related parameters

Tags: julia, structure

I have a mutable structure in Julia

```
@with_kw mutable struct Param
x::Float64 = 0.1
y::Float64 = 1/x
end
```

Now I want to change x to 0.2, so I set
`para = Param()` and `para.x = 0.2`. However, `para.y` does not change. But what I want is to change y automatically, is there any way in Julia to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, Julia isn't so flexible in updating attributes based on other ones. But, gladfully, it's possible to simulate the expected behavior. For this, you need to define a custom `getproperty` function. Suppose I have defined a mutable composite type as follows:

```
julia> Base.@kwdef mutable struct Param
           x::Float64=0.1
       end
Param
```

Now I want to settle the situation to simulate the expected behavior. For this, I go for defining a custom `getproperty` function specifically for `Param`:

```
julia> function Base.getproperty(the_type::Param, prop::Symbol)
           if prop == :y
               return 1/the_type.x
           end
           return getfield(the_type, prop)
       end
```

Now I create an instance of type `Param` holding the default value:

```
julia> instance = Param()
Param(0.1)
```

The output shows just the value of one field (`x`). But meanwhile, we can have the `y` property as we defined our custom `getproperty` function recently:

```
julia> instance.y
10.0
```

Now let's update the `x` field and observe if the `y` field gets updated automatically or not:

```
julia> instance.x = 0.2
0.2

julia> instance.y
5.0
```

Yes, it does!

---

## Further setting

But still, I can't utilize the autocomplete ability of the REPL by hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to write `instance.y`. For this, I can define a custom `propertynames` function specifically for my composite type `Param`:

```
julia> Base.propertynames(the_type::Param) = (:x, :y)

julia> instance. #Hit Tab
x  y
```

Now I can benefit from the autocomplete option in the REPL for `y` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the *default* value for a parameter, not an algorithmic relationship. If `y` is always supposed to be calculated like that and never set on it's own you can define

```
y(p::Param) = 1/p.x
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Just want to confirm, I can not define `y(p::Param) = 1/p.x` inside the structure, and can only do this after the structure is defined, right?